# Navigate JavaScript link

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to click on a link on a web page that will navigate me to another web page and this is a snapshot of the element (I think it is JavaScript link):

[image: dom]

I have tried another part using the same trick but doesn't work this time

[image: dom]

I tried
    .document.getElementById("theBttnbobjid_1518772347342_dialog_submitBtn").Click

and

```
.Navigate "javascript:void(0)"
```

How can I navigate to the desired web page using this element?

Comment: Try `.document.getElementById("LinkButton1").click`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this line and it works fine for me

```
ie.Navigate "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$LinkButton1','')"
```