# VBA closing IE javascript popup

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

The below code opens an instance of InternetExplorer and downloads odds.  It works fine but occasionally a pop-up window appears which causes the code to not work. Any help on how to navigate the below pop-up (i.e. click 'continue to oddschecker') when the pop-up does appear?

```
<a class="continue beta-callout js-close-class" onclick='s_objectID="javascript:void(0)_9";return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true' href="javascript:void(0)">Continue to Oddschecker</a>
```

Full code:

```
Sub Oddschecker()

Dim ie, wp As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = False
ie.Navigate "https://www.oddschecker.com/horse-racing/racing-coupon"

Do While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Do While ie.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Set wp = ie.Document

'Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.ClearContents
Application.Worksheets("sheet1").UsedRange.ClearContents

i = 2
For Each rw In wp.getElementsByTagName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
    If rw.className = "date" Then
        Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1") = rw.innerText
    ElseIf rw.className = "fixture-name" Then
        i = i + 1
        Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i) = rw.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText
        i = i + 1
    ElseIf rw.className = "coupons-table-row match-on" Then
        For Each od In rw.getElementsByTagName("p")
            If InStr(od.innerText, "(") <> 0 Then
                Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i) = Trim(Left(od.innerText, InStr(od.innerText, "(") - 1))
                np = Trim(Right(od.innerText, Len(od.innerText) - InStr(od.innerText, "(")))
                Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B" & i) = Left(np, Len(np) - 1)
                i = i + 1
            Else
                Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i) = Trim(od.innerText)
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next od

    End If
Next rw

ie.Quit

Range("A1:B" & i).WrapText = False
Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Set wp = Nothing
Set ie = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: perhaps a clue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822632/navigate-javascript-link).

Comment: Thanks @ashleedawg.  I've added the following and looks promising: `ie.Navigate "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$LinkButton1','')"`

Comment: So there is no certain way to reproduce this? Also, if you do find a solution, please remember to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to continue with that page (navigating to that popup page), you can try like:

```
Dim HTML As HTMLDocument, addcheck As Object

While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend ''(You can write it the way you feel comfortable)
Set HTML = IE.document  ''place this line after the prevous line

Set addcheck = HTML.querySelector("#promo-modal a.continue")
If Not addcheck Is Nothing Then
    addcheck.Click
End If
```

But, that is not a good idea cause it will lead you to some page where you might need to do some activity to get back on this data ridden page.

I suppose you should get rid of that popup blocker by ticking the cross button located on the top right area and continue to do what you are doing:

```
Dim HTML As HTMLDocument, addcheck As Object

While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend ''(You can write it the way you feel comfortable)
Set HTML = IE.document  ''place this line after the prevous line

Set addcheck = HTML.querySelector("#promo-modal span[title='Close")
If Not addcheck Is Nothing Then
    addcheck.Click
End If
```

If I didn't understand what your intention was, do let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Sim.  Closing the pop-up window is the ideal solution (as the pop-ups can change) but both options do redirect back to the data page.  Option 1: where in the sub do I submit as it seems to crash when I add it in?  For Option 2, I get an error when I run the sub (on the HTML section).  Another problem I have is the pop does not always appear which may be a reason why the sub crashes?

Comment: Are you talking about the `sub` I've pasted above or the one you are using? If you are talking about mine, I don't find any reason for it to crash cause `addcheck.Click` is within `if block` and should only be activated when it finds the `popupblocker`.

Comment: Apologies for not explaining well.  I meant, where in my sub do I call the sub you provided?  Linking it in appears to be where I'm having the problems.  Thanks.

Comment: Now, I've edited my post to make it usable in your script as it is. You can place the one you like (I prefer the second one) within your script just before the line your script crashes for that popup blocker.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I hadn't enabled the HTML Object Library which was causing a problem.  I'm running the code over night and will update tomorrow if all running successfully.